# PixiJS viewport bounce box not centered

Tags: javascript, pixi.js

I am using pixi-viewport in vue 3.
I got the bounce box to work and I've set it up like so:

```
viewport.bounce({
          friction: .1,
          bounceBox: new Rectangle(0, 0,
              window.innerWidth,
              window.innerHeight)
        })
```

But when the image crosses the boundries it bounces back, but not to the center of the screen.
How can I achieve that? I want it to either the center of the screen or the top left.

Thanks in advance.

(Sorry for low frame rate, file was too big)

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/123364387/225952814-75692ab1-c14f-4a3e-87c8-5dd56fe97a4a.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way.

Instead of centering the image by calculating the x & y position based on the window widht & height / 2 minus the image width & height,

```
img.x = (window.innerWidth / 2) - (img.width / 2);
img.y = (window.innerHeight / 2) - (img.height / 2);
```

I used PixiJs-viewport's moveCenter function to center the image:

```
viewport.moveCenter(img.x, img.y);
```

This places the image in the center, and when dragged out of bounds it bounces back to the center as well.